# Does JPA load entities in JPQL, as it does when using entities in code?

Tags: java, jpa

I have a two tables: `Person` and `House`, the mapping is one to one.

Now I have to assign the `address` of `Person` and `House` (which can be different) to the same address.

There are more than 5000 records. Which will be faster? Using Code to update the entities one by one, e.g.

```
for (id : Ids) {
    Person person = PersonDAO.find(id);
    person.setAddress ("abc");
}
```

and then doing same with `House`;

Or should I use JPQL to update both in two different queries, e.g.

```
UPDATE Person p SET p.Address = "abc" WHERE ID IN(.....ID QUERY)
```

My question is what will be faster? Will the update using JPQL have the same performance, same as that in code? Or should I use native query to NOT load the entities, as I only want performance.

Answer (score 0):

Using the query will be faster (and much more memory efficient), as the query provider will translate the JPQL query to native SQL. Also, if you use entities directly, the number of queries made against the database will be siginificantly higher (one select and update for each and every row).

Comment: But will it load entities one by one one and change the Address property ? If it loads then, won't Native will be faster ?

Comment: It won't load the entities, it will only run a single SQL query.

Comment: I think it is very useful answer. If you can please answer can we access joinedColumn entity from a parent entity ? If the entity it is embeddable, it accesses its properties but when we have it just as a simple private variable, it gives error, see above ?

Comment: Of course it gives errrors, JPQL works on entities logically. Some operations can be optimized to physically not use entites, but logically, it always uses them.

Answer (score 0):

The native query will be faster, as it doesn't have to translate anything.

If you want it to be even faster, you can use a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). With the .addBatch() method you add the query to the batch, and with the executeBatch() method you will execute the full batch, minimizing the amount of times being switched between user and kernel mode.

Comment: Can we access House from Person directly in JPAQL ? Person has      house variable with 1:1 mapping and has @JoinedColumn on it but when I try to access House it gives "Incorrect syntax near keyword 'cross'" error. e.g. Update p SET p.Address = 'abc', p.House.Address = 'def'